# Apache Solr comment count not updated

Tags: solr, drupal-7

I have a simple problem. I have an apache solr view that is showing the count of the comments posted for a particular node. When someone deletes a comment the count is not being reflected there. However, after deleting a comment if a new comment is added the count is working properly again.

I've tried `apachesolr_mark_entity()` and `apachesolr_remove_entity()` functions within `hook_comment_delete()`, but without success.

Does anyone have any idea what might be the reason behind it?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: The view displays results corresponding to drupal nodes and for each node the number of comments, that's right ?

Comment: Can you see it in Solr directly? If yes, try issuing a commit and see if it disappears. If it disappears, than the Drupal module is forgetting a commit command.

Comment: @ericLavault: Yes exactly. I am using an apache solr view as previously mentioned and the `is_comment_count` solr field to display the count for that particular drupal node.

@AlexandreRafalovitch: Yes, I have checked in solr directly and it is not showing the reduced count after a comment deletion in there itself. That is why the view is not pulling the correct count in turn. Can you please elaborate what you mean by the commit command and how to implement the same? I am comparatively new to this Solr drupal module.

Comment: The module apachesolr already implements hook_comment_*(), it calls `apachesolr_mark_entity()` for all operations including [comment deletion](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21apachesolr%21apachesolr.module/function/apachesolr_comment_delete/7). Ensure this hook is invoked when a comment is deleted. If it is invoked correctly then the issue may come from your commit policy as @AlexandreRafalovitch suggested.

Comment: `apachesolr_mark_entity()` is indeed called. I have checked that. However, while debugging i found that though this is called, but the node for which the comment is deleted is not actually getting re-indexed. The reason most probably being, in case of deletion this re-indexing is done on the comment entity and not the node entity. Hence the value of the `is_comment_count` field is also not getting updated unlike the scenario when a comment is added. I have come up with a solution that I will post in this thread shortly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a problem with the existing apache solr module.

I have come up with a work-around. Anyone stumbling on this thread in future can post if they find a better solution.

```
/**
* Implements hook_comment_delete().
*/
function yourmodulename_comment_delete($comment) {
  // While deleting a comment, the apache solr comment count field,
  // "is_comment_count" does not get updated unlike comment addition. The reason
  // is while deletion the apache solr module updates the comment entity but not
  // the corresponding node entity. Hence the node needs to be explicitely re-
  // indexed. Since I am already using the "apachesolr_realtime" module , the 
  // "apachesolr_realtime_index_now" function has been used for this purpose.
  // Get the parent node of which this comment belongs to.
  $parent_entity = entity_load('node', array($comment->nid), array(), TRUE);
  $parent_entity = $parent_entity[key($parent_entity)];
  // When the hook_comment_delete function is invoked, the comment count is
  // still not reduced. Hence, drupal_register_shutdown_function has been used so that
  // the call to apachesolr_realtime_index_now is invoked only after the comment
  // and it's corresponding count has been uodated.
  drupal_register_shutdown_function('apachesolr_realtime_index_now', $parent_entity, 'node');
}
```

Thanks